# PowerShell: Capturing Error for [IO.File]::ReadAllText

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I'm trying to figure out how to capture an error message for the following line of PowerShell code (for example, if the user running the script doesn't have permission to read the file):

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\[test].txt")
```

With `Get-Content`, I can simply specify the `ErrorAction` and `ErrorVariable` parameters. This does not seem to be the case with the above line of code.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that with PowerShell v3+, you can get the content as string with: `Get-Content c:\[test].txt -Raw`. Argument `-Raw` was added in v3. Without this `(Get-Content c:\[test].txt).GetType().Name` will return `Object[]` (reads all lines of file into array) as opposed to a single `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a try...catch block

```
try{

    [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\blah")
}
catch{
    #handle here. Catch specific exceptions as well.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `$_.Exception.InnerException` in the catch block.